# Proper Ruby style for multi-line method chaining containing blocks

Tags: ruby, coding-style

The style guide is unclear on this case (other than just giving the opinion that it's weird and it is). I have a chain of hash/array functions to execute on a complex response object. I need to do a few sorts and selections and maps. Currently I just have a long chain of method calls but some of the blocks used for sorting and selecting are multiple lines and some are not.

Should I mix block definition types? Use only braces or only do..end blocks? Should I break it into multiple steps?

Also, if I refactor my blocks and turn them into methods, where would it be appropriate to put them? They don't really make sense in the context of the containing class as instance or class methods.

I looked around and could find no consensus on what is correct style but I am looking for a method that will pass the Ruby Style Guide (so most likely refactoring my blocks into methods, but where do I put them?)

Here is a bit of a contrived example:

```
def example1 (arr)
  arr.sort do |a, b|
    a_pieces = a.value.split ' '
    b_pieces = b.value.split ' '
    (a_pieces[1] + a_pieces[5]) <=> (b_pieces[1] + b_pieces[5])
  end
  .last[:some_value]
  .select do |a|
    a == 'something'
  end

end


def example2 (arr)
  arr.sort { |a, b|
    a_pieces = a.value.split ' '
    b_pieces = b.value.split ' '
    (a_pieces[1] + a_pieces[5]) <=> (b_pieces[1] + b_pieces[5])
  }
  .last[:some_value]
  .select { |a| a == 'something' }
end
```

Comment: Don't use `sort` for this, instead, use [`sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by). It'll be a LOT faster for any sorting operations involving any type of calculations in the block.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would use `do ... end` blocks for *multi-line* and curly braces `{ ... }` for *one-line* code. I never use `do ... end` for *chaining* methods, except when preceding for a *multi-line* block. I also chain methods in the same line as longer as the code is readable and the line is no longer than 80 chars.

So your example I will code it as below:

```
def example1 (arr)
  arr.sort do |a, b|
    a_pieces = a.value.split ' '
    b_pieces = b.value.split ' '
    (a_pieces[1] + a_pieces[5]) <=> (b_pieces[1] + b_pieces[5])
  end.last[:some_value].select { |a| a == 'something' }
end
```

Although I probably will split it in two methods (actually three with the example1 one):

```
def sort_array(arr)
  arr.sort do |a, b|
    a_pieces = a.value.split ' '
    b_pieces = b.value.split ' '
    (a_pieces[1] + a_pieces[5]) <=> (b_pieces[1] + b_pieces[5])
  end
end

def select_item(arr)
  arr.last[:some_value].select { |a| a == 'something' }
end

def example1(arr)
  select_item(sort_array(arr))
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure this would be correct style. Mixing block types looks strange and the style guide suggests that chaining any multiline block is frowned upon.

Comment: To be honest, `end.somethod` also looks weird for me but it enters in conflict of using {} for multiline. So I think to mix here it is the most standard, as far as I see in others.

Comment: I agree with using `do ... end` for multi-line and `{ ... }` for single line blocks. That results in having to mix both styles occasionally, but that is not inherently evil in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, @DaniëlKnippers. I have seen this mix code in SO users with Ks of reputation, but it would be nice to know more opinions.

Comment: I like it done this way, but would prefer `.select...` to be below `.last[...]`, with the dots lined up vertically.

Comment: IntelliJ apparently doesn't format indents when chaining correctly unless the dot is on the preceding line. (The guide says both dot placements are OK)

Comment: Browsing the source of some built-in Ruby gems I do also see a lot of multi-line usage of `{ ... }` for Blocks, though it's not consistent everywhere either..

Comment: Of course, irb and pry can't handle a line beginning with a dot.

Answer (score 5):

I'd do it something like this:

```
def example1(arr)

  arr.sort_by { |a|
    a_pieces = a.value.split
    (a_pieces[1] + a_pieces[5])
  }.last[:some_value]
   .select { |a| a == 'something'}

end
```

`sort` will be *much* slower than [`sort_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) if there is anything beyond a simple `<=>` comparison of simple objects.

Stylistically, use `{`...`}` instead of `do`...`end` if you're returning a value, especially in a chain of methods. The "style *guides*" suggest using `do`...`end` when you're dealing with multiple lines in a block, but `end.some_method` is fugly and confusing. Using `{`...`}` reminds us we are passing only values and cleans up the fugliness.

Remember, they're style *guides*, not laws, and are really common-coding practice guidelines to help us write code readable by everyone. Consistency is important, as is readability.

Also, a bare [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-split) does the same things as `split ' '` or `split(' ')`.